# Android zooming on dynamically changing layers

Tags: android, image, dynamic, layer, zooming

I have the base image of a map and I want to be able to add markers to this map.  The markers are controlled by a set of buttons at the bottom of the screen and need to be able to display and hide whenever the user chooses.  I need to be able to zoom onto the map and the markers need to stay in their correct place.  Getting multiple layers to display is not the problem, it's zooming.

Does anyone know a way I can zoom multiple layers while still retaining the ability to hide and display the markers at any point in time?